# Boost signals : Connect fails

Tags: android, c++, c, boost, android-ndk

I have a public method in a C++ class (let's call it classA) which is defined as:

```
void someFunction(someOtherCppClassB* arg);
```

This 'someFunction' method does the following:

```
theConnection = registerFunction(aPtrToAnInstanceOfCStruct1, boost::bind(&classA::callbackFunction, this, _1));
```

where 'theConnection' is a private member variable in ClassA and it has the type boost::signals2::connection

and where 'callbackFunction' is a private method in classA defined as:

```
int callbackFunction(cStruct2** doublePtr);
```

and where 'aPtrToAnInstanceOfCStruct1' is a pointer to an instance of this C struct:

```
typedef struct cStruct1T
{
       boost::signals2::signal<int (cStruct2**)> signalVariable;
} cStruct1
```

and cStruct2 is defined as:

```
typedef struct cStruct2T
{
   /* Variables in this struct */
       char someDummyVariable;
} cStruct2
```

The 'registerFunction' is defined as:

```
boost::signals2::connection registerFunction(cStruct1* aPtrToAnInstanceOfCStruct1, boost::function<int (cStruct2**)> someCallbackFunction)
{
        /* THIS FAILS FOR SOME REASON */
        return aPtrToAnInstanceOfCStruct1->signalVariable.connect(someCallbackFunction);

}
```

For some reason the .connect() generates the following on Android 4.3:

F/libc    ( 8556): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 8556

I can't figure out what causes the error. So I'm hoping that there's a Boost expert out there who can take a look at the code above and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but I find your example hard to follow. But since it compiles, I suspect that you may have a null pointer, judging by the error code.

I recommend encapsulating the signals code in the class containing the signal and provide a function to connect your `slot` e.g.:

```
typedef struct cStruct1T
{
   typedef boost::signals2::signal<int (cStruct2**)> SignalTypeName;
   SignalTypeName signalVariable;

   void connectSlot(const SignalTypeName::slot_type& slot)
   { signalVariable.connect(slot); }

} cStruct1;
```

You can then register your slot within your `someFunction` like this:

```
aPtrToAnInstanceOfCStruct1->connectSlot(boost::bind(&classA::callbackFunction, this, _1));
```

Comment: That worked. How come 'connectSlot' has to be declared inside the struct?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it worked for you. You don't *have* to declare `connectSlot` inside the struct. Because `signalVariable` is public, you could make the call to `signalVariable.connect(..)`  anywhere. However, I usually declare my signals to be private and so I must provide a method to connect slots to the signals. Also it keeps the signals code together which makes maintenance easier if, for example, `boost::signals2` were to be deprecated like `boost::signals` just was...